# Maven + JSF 2 + Google AppEngine: 404 error

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jsf, maven, jsf-2

I'm trying to run a maven project with jsf on the app engine development server and for every managed bean I get an 404 error (Not found). I edited the files from http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-0-hello-world-example/ to work with GAE. Below are the modified files:

HelloBean.java

```
package com.mkyong.common;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import java.io.Serializable;

@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class HelloBean implements Serializable {
 public String getName() {
  return "abc";
 }
}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <web-app
 version="2.5"
 xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

 <context-param>
  <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
  <param-value>client</param-value>
 </context-param>

 <context-param>
  <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
  <param-value>Development</param-value>
 </context-param>

 <context-param>
  <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
  <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
 </context-param>

 <context-param>
  <param-name>com.sun.faces.enableThreading</param-name>
  <param-value>false</param-value>
 </context-param>

 <!-- Faces Servlet -->
 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
 <!-- Faces Servlet Mapping -->
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

 <!-- Welcome page -->
 <welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>index.jsf</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

index.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

  <h:head>
<title>JSF 2.0 Hello World</title>
</h:head>
 <h:body bgcolor="white">
 <h3>JSF 2.0 Hello World Example - welcome.xhtml</h3>
 <h4>Welcome #{helloBean.name}</h4>
</h:body>
</html>
```

and pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>com.mkyong.common</groupId>
 <artifactId>JavaServerFaces</artifactId>
 <packaging>war</packaging>
 <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <name>JavaServerFaces Maven Webapp</name>
 <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

 <dependencies>
<!-- Google AppEngine -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
   <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
   <version>1.8.5</version>
  </dependency>
  <!-- Servlet dependency -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
   <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
   <version>2.5</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  <!-- JSF -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
   <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
   <version>2.2.4</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
   <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
   <version>2.2.4</version>
  </dependency>    
</dependencies>

 <build>
  <finalName>JavaServerFaces</finalName>

  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
    <configuration>
     <source>1.7</source>
     <target>1.7</target>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>

   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <configuration>
     <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
     <webResources>
      <resource>
       <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
       <filtering>true</filtering>
       <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
      </resource>
     </webResources>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>

   <plugin>
    <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
    <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.5</version>
    <configuration>
     <disableUpdateCheck>true</disableUpdateCheck>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build>
</project>
```

The other files: appengine-web.xml and logging.properties are not changed.

What is wrong? JSF dependencies/configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using JSF 2.2.4 but you *claim* to use JSF 2.0, noted by your hello world example where you just copied/pasted from a tutorial the title *JSF 2.0 Hello World*. Note that JSF 2.2 needs at least Servlet 3.0 API to work but you use Servlet 2.5 API (noted in your maven pom). You have two ways to solve this:

- Downgrade JSF to 2.0. I won't recommend doing this, but will solve the problem.
- Upgrade your servlet API to 3.0. Note that this depends on the servlet version supported by GAE.

Comment: For the first option, I need to change a class inside jsf-api.jar (see http://www.mkyong.com/google-app-engine/google-app-engine-jsf-2-example). The second option is not possible in GAE (https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=3091). It seems there is no solution to use JSF 2.2 in GAE.

Comment: @octavian1001 looks like you can't then. So keep the work with JSF 2.0.